# How to modify the directory date?

Tags: directory

In Windows, I am used to modify directory dates, eg. of directories containing photos according the date when the first photo was taken; and then display a list of the directories sorted by the dates. In Ubuntu, Krusader can display the directories this way.
I need to change the date (the "date of modifying") of a directory after I fill it with eg. the photos. How should I change it? Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use `touch` command with `-t` option. This is from `man touch`:

> ```
> NAME
>        touch - change file timestamps
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        touch [OPTION]... FILE...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Update  the  access  and modification times of each FILE to the current
>        time.
> [...]
>
> -t STAMP
>               use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
> ```

An example:

```
touch -t 1312031429.30 /path/to/directory
```

will change the date modified for `directory` to `2013-12-03 14:29:30`.

Comment: It's useful to note that you must use the `-t` option here.  The `-d` flag present on newer versions of touch does not modify the mtime of a directory, just files.

Answer (score 0):

Don't.  It will just get changed as soon as anything in the directory changes anyhow ( like when a thumbnail is generated ).  Instead, rename the directory so the date you want is in the name.