# How to Change Base Folder Date

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, date

I have a backup drive and keep seven rolling backups for the past seven days using Days of the week within a Bash script.

day-1/home/username/.config

day-2/home/username/.config

When I look at that drive I see

day-1  Nov-26

day-2  Nov-27

day ...

which are the days when that base Folder was created. After the backup has completed, I'd like to change that Base Folder date to today.

I found a link [change date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385370/how-to-modify-the-directory-date) and it mentions that the date will change with the next modification but that base date does not.

In the above example, only the .config Folder has the date changed to today. My guess being that it is only the files farther in being modified and their Parent Folders are being changed to today.

What do I need to do to change that base "day-1" Date?

Comment: What happens when you run `touch day-1`?

Comment: @Ravexina: DUH! So simple, thanks, that looks to be doing it. The test will be with this evening's script run, but manually with the CLI and doing what you asked, does what I wanted.